# Symfony test that runs before any other tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, symfony1

Is there a way to create test that is running before any other tests in the 'test' folder. I'd like to create a test that checks the php.ini settings before any other tests are run.

Comment: If you haven't written much tests, you could switch over to sfPHPUnitPlugin, as it is generally better supported then symfony's built-in test framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Symphony use PHPUnit?  If so, PHPUnit's default behavior will simply read a directory of files and execute them in the order they're listed in by the operating system.  Have you tried reordering files (by renaming, moving, etc) to change the testing order?

Comment: The Symfony yes its own framework as far as i know. But you might be right about tests being run in the order the files are listed. Thanks.